# Android change progressbar color

Tags: android

I want to get circle progressbar and I want to have two color first is white and second blue 
I do this :

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/PROGRESS_BAR"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@color/background_tutorial"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/white"
    android:progressTint="@color/background_tutorial" />
```

But I see only white color I do not see a blue color I see white color and empty view

Comment: What is the lowest supported version of Android in this project?

Comment: @Boken api 21 is min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Idea

The easiest solution working on all of the Android versions is to do the "stack" (e.g. using `RelativeLayout`) using `ImageView` and `ProgressBar`.

**If you are using it in many place, I would recommend to extract it as new View, where you can inflate below layout.**

## Code

**1) Layout**

Example of the implementation:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/progress_bar_background" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/progressBarStyle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

For Android version >= 21 we can use:

```
android:indeterminateTint="#f00"
```

instead of setting `android:theme`.

**2) Style**

To `res/values/styles.xml` we have to add:

```
<style name="progressBarStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

(change color `#FF0000` to your own)

**3) Background ring**
We have to create new file:

`res/drawable/progress_bar_background.xml`

You can name this file as you like, but remember that we are using this name in the layout (in point `1)`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="12"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="#FFFF00" />

</shape>
```

(change color `#FFFF00` to your own)

Here, there is a trick with `thicknessRatio` which is the thickness of the ring expressed as a ratio of the ring's width.

For example, if thicknessRatio=3, then the thickness equals the ring's width divided by 3.

In case of the `ProgressBar` `thicknessRatio` equals 12.

## Demo:

[image: ProgressBar]

## Edit - create new view

1) Extract your layout to file:

```
res/layout/colorful_progress_bar.xml
```

file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/progress_bar_background" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/progressBarStyle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2) Create new view and inflate layout from previous point

```
package com.example

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.widget.RelativeLayout

class ColorfulProgressBar @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : RelativeLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.colorful_progress_bar, this, true)
    }

}
```

3) You this view in your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2F2F2F"
    android:gravity="center">

    <!-- Our own view -->
    <com.example.ColorfulProgressBar
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this.
In your XML layout:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_dialog"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
```

Custom Progress Dialog drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360">
<shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">

    <size android:width="56dip" android:height="56dip" />

    <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
        android:startColor="#fff"
        android:endColor="#0000FF"
        android:angle="0"
        />

</shape>
```

Comment: I do not want to get gradient colors I want to have only two colors white and blue

Comment: Have you tried it? The gradient is almost not noticeable. It can be also easily adjusted to non gradient colors too.

Comment: I try but  I see a gradient color from white to blue I want to get for progress_bar 3/4 -> white and 1/3 _blue

Comment: Simply add to the gradient: android:centerColor="#fff". You will get 3/4 white and 1/4 blue.

Comment: No it is not blue steal I have a blue which go to white and it is 1/4 (good size)

Comment: if this is not what you are looking for post an image of how your progressbar should like , that may help you

Comment: As Android_id has stated, post an image.

Comment: So what I should to do ?